# where can I download the kernel source code for google coral kit?

Tags: google-coral

Does anyone have the kernel source code for the Coral Dev kit? If available, the source code to the entire BSP (rootfs, libaries etc.) would be helpful too...

Answer (score 0):

Try to get the source code from the getting start guide:
https://coral.googlesource.com/docs/+/refs/heads/master/GettingStarted.md